# BDC Model is not visible in Central Administration site

Tags: bdc

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I have created a BDC model using Visual Studio 2012 and deployed in SharePoint 2013. Deployed Solution is visible in Central Admin site and it is activated too. But when I am visiting to BCS Service page, it is not visible in that site. I have Added both the finder and specific finder method and verified the same. The solution works great with SharePoint 2010 but in SharePoint 2013 it is not shown in Central Administration site as well as in the web site.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you set the SiteUrl property in the Feature.xml file? When the property is not present, SharePoint might not be able to find the BDC Service Application.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply. I checked that the site url is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not connecting. Check SQL Server permissions for the identity that is 'connecting as' the target object in the Secure Store.